# SAXParseException prefix not found

Tags: xml, spring, xml-namespaces

I want to integrate my application which work with spring with LDAP but when I try to test I have an error.

the previous config in security-app-context.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/test/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/test1/**" access="hasRole('USER')" />

         <form-login login-page="/index.htm" authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessRedirecthandler"
          default-target-url = "/test/MainHealthCertificat.htm"
            authentication-failure-url="/index.htm?error=1"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/index.htm" />
    </http>

    <beans:bean class="com..CustomAuthenticationHandler" id="authenticationSuccessRedirecthandler"></beans:bean>

        <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
                <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" users-by-username-query="select username, password, enabled from users where username=?"  
                    authorities-by-username-query="select u.username, ur.authority from users u, user_roles ur where u.user_id = ur.user_id and u.username =?  " 
                />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

I try to modify this file using this config:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

        <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
            <intercept-url pattern="/test/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/test1/**" access="hasRole('USER')" />                        
             <form-login login-page="/index.htm" authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessRedirecthandler"
              default-target-url = "/test/MainHealthCertificat.htm"
                authentication-failure-url="/index.htm?error=1"/>
            <logout logout-success-url="/index.htm" />
        </http>

        <beans:bean class="com..CustomAuthenticationHandler" id="authenticationSuccessRedirecthandler"></beans:bean>

    <security:authentication-manager>
         <security:ldap-authentication-provider 
           user-search-filter="(uid={0})"
           user-search-base="ou=users"
           group-search-filter="(uniqueMember={0})"
           group-search-base="ou=groups"
           group-role-attribute="cn"
           role-prefix="ROLE_">
         </security:ldap-authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:ldap-server url="ldap://192.168.0.42:389" manager-dn="uid=admin,ou=system" manager-password="secret" />
</beans:beans>
```

but when I test I have this error:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "security" for element "security:authentication-manager" is not bound.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xerces_2_5_0.jar:]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) [xerces_2_5_0.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75) [spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388) [spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 0):

In both example config files the default namespace is `xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"` which means that unprefixed XML elements will be resolved to that namespace, for example the `<authentication-manager>`.

Other namespaces like `xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"` declare that elements you want to use from the `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans` namespace **must** be prefixed with `beans`. So you could have written `xmlns:coolbeans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"` but then the elements from that namespace would need to be prefixed with `coolbeans`, like `<coolbeans:bean class="com..CustomAuthenticationHandler" id="authenticationSuccessRedirecthandler"></coolbeans:bean>`.

The reason the second example does not work is that a `security` namespace prefix has been added, for example `<security:authentication-manager>` but there is no namespace declared with that prefix.

To fix the problem, remove the `security:` prefix, since the default namespace is already for elements in the `http://www.springframework.org/schema/security` namespace.

Comment: Of the 36 questions you have currently asked, 11 have answers and none of them have been accepted. May I please suggest reading about how Stack Overflow works - http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers